# Ruby - how to get parameters if the request is a post that sends in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have this request that comes in like this:

```
Parameters: {"kpi"=>{"action"=>"create", "users"=>[{"las_name"=>"Doe", "user_id"=>"123", "first_name"=>"John"}, {"las_name"=>"Smith", "user_id"=>"456", "first_name"=>"Anna"}, {"user_id"=>"789", "last_name"=>"Jones", "first_name"=>"Peter"}], "controller"=>"api/kpis"}, "users"=>[{"las_name"=>"Doe", "user_id"=>"123", "first_name"=>"John"}, {"las_name"=>"Smith", "user_id"=>"456", "first_name"=>"Anna"}, {"user_id"=>"789", "last_name"=>"Jones", "first_name"=>"Peter"}]}
```

but it comes as JSON in a POST request so I am not sure how to get it into a local variable.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be `params[:users]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the parameters are showing up like that means that your create action is properly set up to handle JSON as a transport mechanism.  Based on that snippet, you can access these parameters via the `params` hash.

```
kpi = params[:kpi]
@users = kpi["users"]
```